# How to understand/derive Eq 5.5 in Geiner's Quantum Mechanics - An Introduction?

Tags: units, thermal-radiation, unit-conversion, blackbody

Geiner's Quantum Mechanics - An Introduction has an unnumbered equation above Eq. 6 in section 2.4 discussing density -- not sure if it is energy density -- of radiation:

> ...
>   $$dE/dV = E/V =a T^4$$
>   where 
>   $$a = \frac{\pi^2 k_B^4}{15 \hbar^3 c^3} = 7.56 \times 10^{-15} erg cm^{-3} K^{-4}$$
>   This gives rise to an homogeneous, isotropic,radiation of density K, where K is given by
>
> $$K = \frac{c}{4 \pi} \frac{dE}{dV} erg \: cm^{-2}$$
>   ...

I'm particularly puzzled by the factor of $\frac{c}{4\pi}$.  How is it from? Hopefully this is enough info for the question to be answerable.

Comment: It's probably due to the stupid units. Erg cm etc